# Request is not finished when using SqlDataReader in FileStreamResult using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, filestream, sqlconnection

For performance considerations I am using `SqlConnection` and `SqlReaderStream` for returning a `byte[]` **stream from a SQL Server database**:

```
private static SqlConnection GetConnection()
{
    var sqlConnectionStringBuilder =
        new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StudentsSystemEntities"].ConnectionString)
            {
                Pooling = true
            };
    var connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();
    return connection;
}

public FileDownloadModel GetFileById(Guid fileId)
{
    var connection = GetConnection();
    var command = new SqlCommand(
        @"SELECT [FileSize], [FileExtension], [Content] FROM [dbo].[Files] WHERE [FileId] = @fileId;",
        connection);
    var paramFilename = new SqlParameter(@"fileId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier) { Value = fileId };
    command.Parameters.Add(paramFilename);

    var reader = command.ExecuteReader(
        CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess | CommandBehavior.SingleResult
        | CommandBehavior.SingleRow | CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    if (reader.Read() == false) return null;

    var file = new FileDownloadModel
                    {
                        FileSize = reader.GetInt32(0),
                        FileExtension = reader.GetString(1),
                        Content = new SqlReaderStream(reader, 2)
                    };
    return file;
}
```

I am using this `GetFileById` method in **ASP.NET MVC action**:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get(string id)
{
    // Validations omitted

    var file = this.filesRepository.GetFileById(guid);

    this.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    this.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromDays(365));
    this.Response.Cache.SetSlidingExpiration(true);

    this.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.FileSize.ToString());
    var contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(
        string.Format("file.{0}", file.FileExtension));
    // this.Response.BufferOutput = false;
    return new FileStreamResult(file.Content, contentType);
}
```

I am connecting the MVC `FileStreamResult` with the `SqlReaderStream` in the following line:

```
return new FileStreamResult(file.Content, contentType);
```

When I try to load the resource using Chrome (or Firefox...) **the entire file is loaded but I am getting the following error:**

> CAUTION: request is not finished yet!

[image: CAUTION: request is not finished yet!]

**Response headers:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Content-Length: 33429
Content-Type: image/png
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcR---trimmed---G5n?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 28 Jul 2015 13:02:55 GMT
```

**Additional information:**

- I am not using any Chrome extensions
- The problem is only with the given `Get` action. All other actions are loading normally
- The `FilesController` (in which the `Get` action is) inherits directly from the `Controller` class
- The file is loading successfully but the browser is still waiting the server: [image]
- The exact same problem I am having with Firefox

**What are the possible causes of the problem?**

**Source code of the `SqlReaderStream` class**

```
public class SqlReaderStream : Stream
{
    private readonly int columnIndex;

    private SqlDataReader reader;

    private long position;

    public SqlReaderStream(
        SqlDataReader reader, 
        int columnIndex)
    {
        this.reader = reader;
        this.columnIndex = columnIndex;
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get { return this.position; }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var bytesRead = this.reader.GetBytes(
            this.columnIndex, this.position, buffer, offset, count);
        this.position += bytesRead;
        return (int)bytesRead;
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && null != this.reader)
        {
            this.reader.Dispose();
            this.reader = null;
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post code for `SqlReaderStream`? Issue might be inside this class.

Comment: Sure :). See my edited post.

Comment: This could be the problem of "Keep-Alive" which why the connection is not being terminated from server.

Comment: Does your `[Content]` field really contain 33429 bytes of data? Or does it have less?  What value do you get when you execute: `reader.GetBytes(2, 0, null, 0, 0);`?

Comment: I think there is no way that the `FileStreamResult` knows the stream has ended. You don't return the `Length` and also don't have the `EndOfStream` property

Comment: try `this.reader.GetBytes(
            this.columnIndex, offset, buffer, 0, count);`

Comment: Try proactively closing your SqlDataReader inside your SqlReaderStream.Read when you detect that bytesRead==0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem is that in this line:

```
this.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.FileSize.ToString());
```

you are giving away a wrong filesize which is larger than the real file size. This is why browsers are waiting for additional content.

To quickly check that this is indeed the issue, modify the line to the following

```
this.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", (file.FileSize/10).ToString());
```

This will limit a download to 1/10th of the file in question - but since filesizes are probably off much less than by an order of magnitude,
the files will have enough data to serve 10 percent of the asked filesize, 
and the issue will not be reproducible anymore.

Comment: This was the issue! Thank you very much. To be precise I've fixed it by not sending `Content-Length` header to the browser (removing `this.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.FileSize.ToString());` line)

Comment: I don't usually leave thanks.. it just clutters up the responses, but I had to make an exception.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I would not return `SqlReaderStream` in `FileStreamResult`, because the stream is not **seekable**. I guess it could be a problem.

Try to copy the `Stream` to `MemoryStream` or **byte array** and return it in `GetFileById` instead.

Furthermore you can close the connection to database if you read the `SqlReaderStream` locally in function.

```
return File(byteArray, contentType, name);
```

Comment: this solution is not suitable for large files,  i used this method for long time, but now I need to handle large files and it doesn't work like before (sometimes nothing happens :)

Answer (score -1):

This problem is related to Chrome Browser,only when the first request is not completed. Try using Firefox or Safari.

See Links below for further info. http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/821716/PHP-serve-MP-Chrome-Provisional-headers-are-shown

["CAUTION: provisional headers are shown" in Chrome debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger)

[Chrome block requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521755/chrome-block-requests)

Comment: As I've mentioned in the question: `The exact same problem I am having with Firefox`